# css modal box not working

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a modal box, here is my html

```
<div id="sign_up_box">     // this should be transparent
 <div id="signup_form">     // this should be opaque 
  <button type="button">X Close</button>
  <form method="POST" action="signup_pro.php">
    <label>Name</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="username"/></br>
    <label>Email</label></br>
    <input type="email" name="email"/></br>
    <label>Password</label></br>
    <input type="password" name="password"/></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Account"/>
  </form>
 </div> 
</div>
```

here is my css

```
#sign_up_box {
  position:absolute;;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  bottom:0%;
  right:0%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: crimson;
  opacity:0.5;
  display:none;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  }

#signup_form {
 position:absolute;
 top:30%;
 left:40%;
 z-index:9999;
 opacity:1 !important;
 background-color:white;
 width:30%;
 min-width:100px;
 padding:2px;
  }
#signup_form form{
   margin:5% auto;
   width:80%;
   opacity:1;
  }
```

I have div inside another div, i want outer div to be transparent but inner div to be totally opaque.
but here i am unable to override the the parents opacity property as a result the inner div is transparent as well. can anyone suggest a solution? jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/manu2784/z5qrwfgv/

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please>?

Comment: posted an answer based on what I understand you are trying to do - since the posted code here does not have the JS and the code in the fiddle does not trigger the open/close behaviour, I tried my best with what I had :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try taking the form out of the backdrop. As in:

```
<div id="sign_up_box">// this should be transparent</div>
<div id="signup_form">// this should be opaque
    <button type="button">X Close</button>
    <form method="POST" action="signup_pro.php">
        <label>Name</label>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        </br>
        <label>Email</label>
        </br>
        <input type="email" name="email" />
        </br>
        <label>Password</label>
        </br>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oxfuc4et/1/**

(I took out `display:none` from the css only for demo purposes, I believe you will be doing that on button click yourself, right?)

Comment: thanks this did work, but i had to set the opacity of the background and the modal box separately.

Answer (score 0):

Take this out `display:none`[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0hrrzyy/)

Comment: tried, doesn't work. anyone display:none is to hide dialog box when not in use, nothing to do with opacity.

Comment: ? I couldn't see anything with display set to none, and display:none does have alot to do with opacity, kinda like setting opacity to 0, although opacity would keep the space in the flow

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

```
display:none
```

Are you trying something  [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ofxfrkhs/)

Comment: i am setting the display to block on click using jquery.

Comment: changing the background to back to 'crimson' shows that transparency did not work

Comment: please add your fiddle